# What is wrong with this StringReplace code?

Tags: replace, autohotkey

I have this string `XXX:ABC`. I want to remove `XXX:` so that the string becomes `ABC` .

The variable `Symbol` contains the string `XXX:ABC` .

The code as follows:

```
MsgBox, Symbol %Symbol%
SearchText := "XXX:"
ReplaceText := ""
StringReplace, newSymbol, Symbol, SearchText, ReplaceText, ALL 
MsgBox, newSymbol %newSymbol%
```

From the message box output, `newSymbol` content is the same as `Symbol`. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

I am using Autohotkey v1.1.14.03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For command parameters, you have to distinguish between *variable parameters* and *value parameters*.
`StringReplace` for instance has the following argument list:

> StringReplace, **OutputVar**, **InputVar**, SearchText [, ReplaceText,
>   ReplaceAll?]

The docs say furthermore:

> OutputVar: The **name of the variable** in which to store the result
>   of the replacement process.
>
> InputVar: The **name of the variable** whose contents will be read
>   from.
>
> SearchText: The **string** to search for.

As you can see, some parameters are expected to be **variable names**, whereas others are expected to be **values** like strings or numbers. You can use variable contents as value parameters by either enclosing them in percent signs or using them within an expression:

```
StringReplace, newSymbol, Symbol, %SearchText%, %ReplaceText%, ALL
; or as an expression
StringReplace, newSymbol, Symbol, % SearchText, % ReplaceText, ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

With the newer StrReplace() function I noticed I could not use it with variables for whatever reason. And the documentation here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm
is lacking an example. After a lot of tests, couldn't figure it out.
So I wrote a "**polyfill**" for StrReplace, complete with test code.

```
; Author: John Mark Isaac Madison
; EMAIL : J4M4I5M7@hotmail.com
; I_SRC : input source text
; I_OLD : old token to find
; I_NEW : new token to replace old with
FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE(I_SRC, I_OLD, I_NEW)
{
    ;Check length of input parameters:
    ;--------------------------------------------;
    L1 := StrLen(I_SRC)
    L2 := StrLen(I_OLD)
    L3 := StrLen(I_NEW)
    if( !(L1 > 0)  )
    {
        msgbox BAD_PARAM_#1:STR_REP
    }
    if( !(L2 > 0)  )
    {
        msgbox BAD_PARAM_#2:STR_REP
    }
    if( !(L3 > 0)  )
    {
        msgbox BAD_PARAM_#3:STR_REP
    }
    ;--------------------------------------------;


    OP := "" ;output string

    f_ptr := 0 ;fill pointer
    max_i := StrLen(I_SRC)
    dx := 0 ;<--Loop counter / index
    LOOP  ;;[LOOP_START];;
    {
        dx++
        if(dx > max_i)
        {
            break ;[BAIL_OUT_OF_LOOP]
        }

        h := FN_IS_TOKEN_HERE(I_SRC, I_OLD, dx)

        ;if(8==dx)
        ;{
        ;    msgbox, HACK_8 dx[%dx%]  h[%h%] I_SRC[%I_SRC%]  I_OLD[%I_OLD%]
        ;    src_len := StrLen( I_SRC )
        ;    old_len := StrLen( I_OLD )
        ;    msgbox src_len [%src_len%]  old_len[%old_len%] I_OLD[%I_OLD%]
        ;}

        if( h > 0)
        {
            ;token found, replace it by concating
            ;the I_NEW onto output string:
            OP := OP . I_NEW
            ;OP := OP . "[X]"

            ;msgbox : I_SRC[%I_SRC%]  h[%h%]  dx[%dx%]

            ;jump pointer to last character of
            ;the found token to skip over
            ;now irrelevant characters:
            dx := h

            ;msgbox, DX: %dx%
        }
        else
        if( 0 == h)
        {
            msgbox, "H_SHOULD_NOT_BE_ZERO"
        }
        else
        if( h < 0 )
        {
            ;concat character to output:
            c := SubStr(I_SRC,dx,1)
            OP := OP . c
        }

    }     ;;[LOOP_END];;


    msgbox OP : %OP%
    ;msgbox I_SRC[ %I_SRC%] I_OLD[ %I_OLD%] I_NEW[ %I_NEW%]
    return OP ;;<--return output string

}


;Author: John Mark Isaac Madison
;EMAIL : J4M4I5M7@hotmail.com
;unit-test that will run when script boots up:
FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE_TEST()
{
    T1 := FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE("WHAT_IS_UP","UP","DOWN")
    ;;msgbox, T1 : %T1%

    i_src := "123_TOKEN_123"
    i_old := "TOKEN"
    i_new := "NEEEW"
    T2  := FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE(i_src,i_old,i_new)
    ;;msgbox, T2 : %T2%

    ;;msgbox, "POLYFILL_TEST_RAN"


    i_src := "const IS_VARNAME"
    i_old := "VARNAME"
    i_new := "BASH"
    T3  := FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE(i_src,i_old,i_new)
    ;msgbox, T3 : %T3%

    i_src := "123456VARNAME"
    i_old := "VARNAME"
    i_new := "AB"
    T4  := FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE(i_src,i_old,i_new)

    if(T1 != "WHAT_IS_DOWN")
    {
        msgbox [PSR_TEST_FAIL#1]
    }

    if(T2 != "123_NEEEW_123")
    {
        msgbox [PSR_TEST_FAIL#2]
    }

    if(T3 != "const IS_BASH")
    {
        msgbox [PSR_TEST_FAIL#3]
    }

    if(T4 != "123456AB")
    {
        msgbox [PSR_TEST_FAIL#4]
    }


    return ;rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr;
}
FN_POLYFILL_STR_REPLACE_TEST()
```

Also, be aware that trimming out **newlines** in your data is harder than it
should be as well. And will be bound to throw a monkey wrench into whatever string parsing you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Problem still exists in newer versions.

solve by this alternative syntax for expressions:

`newSymbol := StrReplace(Symbol, "" . SearchText, "" . ReplaceText)`