# StringReplace illegal character

Tags: string, replace, autohotkey

I am trying to replace commas using a code like this:

```
OrigQtyC := "70,000"
StringReplace, OrigQty, %OrigQtyC%, `, , All
MsgBox, %OrigQty%
```

Running a script containing the code above returns the following error:

```
Error: The following variable name contains an illegal character: "70,000"
```

I guess the illegal character is the comma, although I am not able to figure out why it should be illegal.

I would like to replace the comma with blank (empty).

Neither from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171779/what-is-wrong-with-this-stringreplace-code?rq=1) nor [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023906/autohotkey-error-variable-name-contains-an-illegal-character-100-000000?rq=1) questions I've figured out what's wrong with my use of that command.

Comment: ``StringReplace, OrigQty, OrigQtyC, `, , All``

Comment: Then, when the StringReplace command reference says "_Do not enclose the name in percent signs unless you want the **contents** of the variable to be used as the name._", its meaning is not so clear... isn't the **content** of `OrigQty` the number `70,000` and using `%` supposed to return its content?

Comment: @LisaAnn `OutputVar` or `InputVar` are expected to be **variable names**. If you enclose a variable in percent signs, you are telling `StringReplace` to use its content as the name. Example: You have a variable `x := "myvar"` and another variable `myvar := "Hello"`. Now, you're calling `StringReplace, result, %x%, e, a`. `result` will now contain `Hallo`, since `%x%` resolves to the variable `myvar`, which contains `Hello`. Regarding our example, `StringReplace` is looking for the variable `70,000`, thowing an error since a variable name can't contain commas.